# i7 2600K over heating

Tags: intel-core-i7

I just bought and installed an i7 2600K CPU with a BIOSTAR TP67XE motherboard.

When I first started up the comp, I went into the bios and and said that my CPU was at 79C and it kept climbing (within minutes) to 90 degrees.

What is the normal temp for an i7 2600K? Is this normal?

I am still worried about the heatsink mounting. It was very weird to install and gave you no clue as to weather it was done correctly.

I just bought a aftermarket heatsink (will be here in a few days) because I planed on overclocking.

Are these temperatures normal? With the temperature rising so fast within the BIOS, do you think that is a good indicator that the heatsink wasn't mounted properly?

Comment: When you installed the heatsink/fan, did you apply thermal grease to the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not normal.. that is VERY hot for a CPU, I would not run it at that temperature at all. The heatsink is either not mounted properly or secure enough... or the thermal compound on the bottom of the heatsink that touches the CPU is bad or not spread around well enough. the heatsinks do fit onto the motherboard quite snug, and it is a challenge to get all of the legs popped through the holes and secured, I suggest doing this when the motherboard is out of the case because then you can see if the pins are poking all of the way through.

Comment: Do you think I ruined my CPU? The CPU hasn't went passed 92C.